# What is behind a silent failure to load resource on x64 bit machine with .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, crash

A user of my program has reported an inability to startup the application. I am not yet done troubleshooting, but I'm simply baffled.

Logging still works, so I used logging statements and was able to narrow down the crash to a single line in a user control's InitializeComponent:

> this.HorizontalBox.Image =
>   ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("HorizontalBox.Image")));

Here are the relevant clues from his end:

- 64 bit Windows 7
- Correct .NET Framework (4.0 Client Profile)
- No visual elements ever show, and no error dialogs. It is a silent shutdown when starting.
- Logging works, but there were no logged errors.
- He has uninstalled and reinstalled the .NET 4.0 Client Profile framework.
- He doesn't have any Visual Studio or other development tools mucking with stuff.

I have spent a week or so eliminating theories and I'm becoming confused and desperate. Here are relevant details and things I have found:

- I am targeting x86 explicitly.
- The logging which failed to log any exception is set up to catch and log any unhandled exceptions and thread abort exceptions.
- Whatever is killing the application also prevents the final "shutting down" logging message in the program's basic entry point.
- I had read that certain icon (.ICO) file formats don't work in Windows XP. A far fetched theory, since this is Windows 7. This is the one and only case of ICO files in the project, so I was suspicious and switched it to PNG. No difference. I since figure that the image is failing merely because it is the first image loaded from a resource.
- I had read that the Form_Load event may swallow exceptions (and only when debugging). Also, InitializeComponent() is in the constructor, so the theory was shaky. Nonetheless, I wrapped the call to InitializeComponent() in a try/catch, but the catch and its associated logging never get called.
- I have seen posts about resource compilation problems between x86 and x64, but nothing relevant to runtime issues. (See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/19/resgen-exe-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format.aspx?PageIndex=3#comments))
- I assumed there must be something wrong unique with the program showing issues, so I made a WindowsFormsApplication1 test application with nothing more than a single image embedded in the associated resource file. This also fails to load in the same way. This test application was also targeting x86.
- It works fine on other x86 and x64 machines!

What could possibly be going on his machine? Why is exception handling failing me? This problem is crazy!

**Edit: More Details, and I'm still baffled!**

- I have since sent the test application (a single form with a single image on it) built as x86, x64, and "Any Cpu". The x64 and "Any Cpu" applications both work.

Comment: Looks like some kind of a schroedingbug. Could it be that the windows is a bit messed up ? Because if it is the case, it might be impossible to debug your program, if the problem is coming from the computers system itself. Also, note that some exceptions are uncatchable, and just crash the program if they occur.

Comment: I had a similar problem a while ago. My application, using ICO files, built on Win7 was suddenly crashing on XP. I replaced the ICO file by a PNG and everything went well. What does the system event log say? Can you remotely log into the machine? You could debug it using WinDBG/SOS and see what the hell is going on there. If you can't debug it remotely, ask your user to run the software for you and create a full dump, that can help as well.

Comment: If you can get this occurring reliably on a machine, your only resort is probably going to be using windbg. It's a learning curve that's quite steep, but once you get some basics down is very handy in debugging things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some questions spring to mind. Have you got a similar build machine with which to test - this may help to identify if it is the build/program integration or some possible issue with his build (i.e. a windows problem/virus/etc).

Has he installed to the default folder or did he do a customised install?

Has he tried a full uninstall / reinstall of your app? (I note you said the runtime was refreshed) - possibly to a different folder to make sure.

Can you recreate on a similar build (OS version) with VS installed to do a code walkthrough in the debugger - stack trace and output buffer may help identify - so may disasembly - and can set it to stop at all exceptions?

Unfortunatly unhandled exceptions can not always be caught in C# (especially post 2.0) - so a debugger of WinDBG may be your only option in the end (yuk!).

Can I suggest something though first...Just a thought:

Before the line that fails, as a test, output something like this:

```
var obj = resources.GetObject("HorizontalBox.Image");
        Console.WriteLine("Obj = " + (obj is Bitmap));
```

Because I have a feel that the failure is happening when trying to marshal the resource into the Bitmap Type and getting a memory exception (maybe something corrupt with the image stride/pixel format etc or maybe something on the culprit machine is making the image file look like a non image file).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Wolf. Unfortunately, I never *actually* solved this. I was down to the last resort you mentioned: using a debugger. I didn't actually do this, because it was on a remote end user's machine.